# Redux-Form - validation happens only once

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I'm new to redux-form, and I followed this simple example: http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/examples/syncValidation/

I did everything it says but for some reason the validation function I'm passing is invoked only once, at the creation of the form, and it doesn't invoke when values are changed.

Here is my code:

reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form/immutable';

export const appReducers = combineReducers({
    form: formReducer
});
```

my form:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import TextField from 'react-mdl';

class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            user: Map({
                id: '',
                name: ''
            })
        };

        this.onIdChange = this.onIdChange.bind(this);
        this.onNameChange = this.onNameChange.bind(this);
    }

    onIdChange(event) {
        // change the id in the user.
    }

    onNameChange(event) {
        // change the name in the user.
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

        return (<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Field name='id'
                    label='id'
                    component={TextField}
                    onChange={this.onIdChange}
                    value={this.state.user.get('id')} />
                <Field name='name'
                    label='name'
                    component={TextField}
                    onChange={this.onNameChange}
                    value={this.state.user.get('name')}/>
            </form>);
    }
}

const validate = values => {
    const errors = {};

    if (!values.id) {
        errors.id = 'Required';
    }

    if (!values.name) {
        errors.name = 'Required';
    }

    return errors;
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'userForm',
    validate
})(Form);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you are using an immutable import

   `import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form/immutable';`

   for the reducer. You should also use the same for the actual form imports like this:

   `import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form/immutable';`
2. If this doesn't fix the problem I think there's something wrong with onChange and the custom handlers you defined(onNameChange) that are changing inner state.
3. Also remember to always pass down the `{...input}` from props to your custom input component (it includes redux-form onChange,... needed).
   like this:

   `const renderField = ({ input, label, type }) => (
     <div>
       <label>{label}</label>
       <div>
         <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type}/>
       </div>
     </div>
   )`

Comment: Hi, I tried to import Field and reduxForm from redux-form/immutable and it still didnt work, I also removed the onChange and the value binding and it still didnt work.

Comment: In Redux-dev-tools while typing in any fields of the form do you see `redux-form/CHANGE` getting dispatched? also seeing `redux-form/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS` means error message is getting dispatched too but there's something wrong with showing it.

Comment: I see that redux-from/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS is dispatched once at first and then redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD is being dispatched twice and thats it. When I type nothing is being dispatched

Comment: if you don't get `redux-form/CHANGE` remove `onChange` and `value` props completely, since it's actually not needed and redux-form pass the props down to you custom component. There's no need to have an state for controlled input, all values in form are in redux single store. I think your problem is overriding onChange handler of redux-form so it doesn't dispatch `redux-form/CHANGE`. no new value = nothing new to validate again after form initial values.

Comment: So I removed the onChange and value but nothing happend, so I tried replacing the textfield with a regular input and it worked, so probably there is something wrong with my component. Thanks

Comment: @Pachu oh so didn't you pass down the {...input} from props to your custom input component? see this example and how it's implemented http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/examples/syncValidation/

Answer (score 0):

I know this wasn't the original asker's issue, but in case anyone is running into this same issue while using `redux-form/immutable`, be sure to access your `values` within your validate function as Immutable data types, e.g. using the `.get()` method instead of normal dot notation. Seems simple, but easy to miss if you're following examples from the docs.